# EntityNotFoundException - Spring mvc cant query object with abstract class property, but can query property object. And only on certain inheritances

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I'm using a Spring MVC - Hibernate - MySQL project template provided by my college to do a project.

This project has an abstract class Actor, and 6 classes extend Actor: Administrator, Explorer, Manager, Ranger, Auditor and Sponsor.

On the other hand, there are Messages, which have a sender (Actor), a collection of recipients (Actor) and various other properties that do not matter.

The problem is that I cant do operations that involve selecting a Message from the database which have either an sender or recipient which isn't a Ranger. It does work fine in every other case.

I have an utilitie called QueryDatabase on which I can do queries on the eclipse console. In this layer, converters do not matter as it's simple querying, so the problem isn't on the converters, as even on querying I have this problem.

I can't select a Message which has an admin sender:

```
> select m from Message m where m.sender.id=342;

javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find domain.Actor with id 342
```

However, I can select the sender of that message:

```
> select m.sender from Message m where m.sender.id=342;
1 object selected
domain.Administrator{id=342, version=0}
    domain.DomainEntity::id: int = 342
    domain.DomainEntity::version: int = 0
    domain.Actor::name: java.lang.String = "Mark"
    domain.Actor::surname: java.lang.String = "Kilo"
    domain.Actor::email: java.lang.String = "markkilo@go.es"
    domain.Actor::phone: java.lang.String = "6662637633"
    domain.Actor::address: java.lang.String = "Ulises Street,12,London"
    domain.Actor::isSuspicious: boolean = false
    domain.Actor::isBanned: boolean = false
    domain.Actor::folders: java.util.Collection = [domain.Folder{id=343, version=0}, domain.Folder{id=344, version=0}, domain.Folder{id=345, version=0}, domain.Folder{id=346, version=0}, domain.Folder{id=347, version=0}, domain.Folder{id=348, version=0}]
    domain.Actor::socialEntities: java.util.Collection = []
    domain.Actor::userAccount: security.UserAccount = security.UserAccount{id=329, version=0}
```

I can also select an Actor which is that administrator just by it's id:

```
> select a from Actor a where a.id=342;
1 object selected
domain.Administrator{id=342, version=0}
    domain.DomainEntity::id: int = 342
    domain.DomainEntity::version: int = 0
    domain.Actor::name: java.lang.String = "Mark"
    domain.Actor::surname: java.lang.String = "Kilo"
    domain.Actor::email: java.lang.String = "markkilo@go.es"
    domain.Actor::phone: java.lang.String = "6662637633"
    domain.Actor::address: java.lang.String = "Ulises Street,12,London"
    domain.Actor::isSuspicious: boolean = false
    domain.Actor::isBanned: boolean = false
    domain.Actor::folders: java.util.Collection = [domain.Folder{id=343, version=0}, domain.Folder{id=344, version=0}, domain.Folder{id=345, version=0}, domain.Folder{id=346, version=0}, domain.Folder{id=347, version=0}, domain.Folder{id=348, version=0}]
    domain.Actor::socialEntities: java.util.Collection = []
    domain.Actor::userAccount: security.UserAccount = security.UserAccount{id=329, version=0}
```

And, as I said, I can select a Message which sender/recipients are rangers:

```
> select m from Message m where m.sender.id=403;
11 objects selected
domain.Message{id=472, version=0}
    domain.DomainEntity::id: int = 472
    domain.DomainEntity::version: int = 0
    domain.Message::LOW: java.lang.String = "LOW"
    domain.Message::NEUTRAL: java.lang.String = "NEUTRAL"
    domain.Message::HIGH: java.lang.String = "HIGH"
    domain.Message::subject: java.lang.String = "House Fix"
    domain.Message::body: java.lang.String = "We have to fix the widnow in the liing room"
    domain.Message::moment: java.util.Date = <<2016-07-12 00:00:00.0>>
    domain.Message::priority: java.lang.String = "HIGH"
    domain.Message::sender: domain.Actor = domain.Ranger{id=403, version=0}
    domain.Message::recipients: java.util.Collection = [domain.Ranger{id=409, version=0}]

etc
```

However, I can query entities that have, for example, "Administrator" or "Explorer" type properties and instantieted properties of that concrete type.

So, the problem is only when I query for an entity that has an Actor (abstract) property, and the instantiated property is of an extended Actor class which isn't Ranger.

All the tags and extensions I was told to put are the same on all the classes so, any idea on where it could be going wrong?

All the tags and imported libraries are the same on the domain and repository files, and all of them extend actor.

Rangers are neither the first class to get instantiated nor the last.

I can't find anything different on Rangers that makes it work for them.

If you need any other piece of code, let me know, but I don't even know what would be useful as everything seems redundant to me.

Thanks for reading.

EDIT: Forgot to say, this does not happen just with Message. It also happens with SocialEntity, which has a similar property.

EDIT2: Gonna add the code of the entities just in case someone notices anything strange:

Message:

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Message extends DomainEntity {



// Priority Values -----------------------------------------------------------------

    public static final String LOW = "LOW";
    public static final String NEUTRAL = "NEUTRAL";
    public static final String HIGH = "HIGH";



    private String  subject;
    private String  body;
    private Date    moment;
    private String  priority;

    private Actor   sender;
    private Collection<Actor>   recipients;

    @NotBlank
    public String getSubject() {
        return this.subject;
    }
    public void setSubject(final String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    @NotBlank
    public String getBody() {
        return this.body;
    }
    public void setBody(final String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }


    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    public Date getMoment() {
        return this.moment;
    }
    public void setMoment(final Date moment) {
        this.moment = moment;
    }

    @NotBlank
    @Pattern(regexp = "^" + LOW + "|" + NEUTRAL + "|" + HIGH + "$")
    public String getPriority() {
        return this.priority;
    }
    public void setPriority(final String priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Valid
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    public Actor getSender() {
        return this.sender;
    }
    public void setSender(final Actor sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }
    @NotEmpty
    @Valid
    @ManyToMany
    public Collection<Actor> getRecipients() {
        return this.recipients;
    }
    public void setRecipients(final Collection<Actor> recipients) {
        this.recipients = recipients;
    }
}
```

Actor:

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Actor extends DomainEntity {

private String                      name;
private String                      surname;
private String                      email;
private String                      phone;
private String                      address;
private boolean                     isSuspicious;
private boolean                     isBanned;

private Collection<Folder>          folders;
private Collection<SocialEntity>    socialEntities;

private UserAccount                 userAccount;


@NotBlank
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@NotBlank
public String getSurname() {
    return this.surname;
}

public void setSurname(final String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}

@Email
public String getEmail() {
    return this.email;
}

public void setEmail(final String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return this.phone;
}

public void setPhone(final String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return this.address;
}

public void setAddress(final String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@NotNull
@Valid
public Collection<Folder> getFolders() {
    return this.folders;
}

public void setFolders(final Collection<Folder> folders) {
    this.folders = folders;
}

@ElementCollection
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "actor")
@NotNull
public Collection<SocialEntity> getSocialEntities() {
    return this.socialEntities;
}

public void setSocialEntities(final Collection<SocialEntity> socialEntities) {
    this.socialEntities = socialEntities;
}

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@NotNull
public UserAccount getUserAccount() {
    return this.userAccount;
}

public void setUserAccount(final UserAccount userAccount) {
    this.userAccount = userAccount;
}


public boolean getIsSuspicious() {
    return isSuspicious;
}

public void setIsSuspicious(boolean isSuspicious) {
    this.isSuspicious = isSuspicious;
}

public boolean getIsBanned() {
    return isBanned;
}

public void setIsBanned(boolean isBanned) {
    this.isBanned = isBanned;
}
```

Ranger:

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Ranger extends Actor {

    private Curricula           curricula;
    private Collection<Trip>    trips;


    @NotNull
    @OneToOne(optional = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Curricula getCurricula() {
        return this.curricula;
    }

    @Valid
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ranger")
    public Collection<Trip> getTrips() {
        return this.trips;
    }

    public void setCurricula(final Curricula curricula) {
        this.curricula = curricula;
    }

    public void setTrips(final Collection<Trip> trips) {
        this.trips = trips;
    }
```

And, for example, Administrator. If you need more than this, let me know:

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Administrator extends Actor{

}
```

EDIT3: Examples of populating beans for actors;

Administrator:

```
<bean id="admin1" class="domain.Administrator">

        <property name="name" value="Mark" />
        <property name="surname" value="Kilo" />
        <property name="email" value="markkilo@go.es" />
        <property name="phone" value="6662637633" />
        <property name="address" value="Ulises Street,12,London" />
        <property name="folders">
            <list>
                <ref bean="sys-admin1"/>
                <ref bean="inbox-admin1" />
                <ref bean="outbox-admin1" />
                <ref bean="notifbox-admin1" />
                <ref bean="trashbox-admin1" />
                <ref bean="spambox-admin1" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="socialEntities">
            <list>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="userAccount" ref="adminUserAccount" />
        <property name="isSuspicious" value="false" />
        <property name="isBanned" value="false" />
    </bean>
```

Ranger:

```
<bean id="ranger1" class="domain.Ranger">
        <property name="name" value="Paco" />
        <property name="surname" value="Pepe" />
        <property name="email" value="franciscojose@gmail.com" />
        <property name="phone" value="953547272" />
        <property name="address" value="C\ Alpha nº69" />
        <property name="userAccount" ref="rangerUserAccount" />
        <property name="isSuspicious" value="false" />
        <property name="isBanned" value="false" />
        <property name="folders">
            <list>
                <ref bean="inbox-ranger1" />
                <ref bean="outbox-ranger1" />
                <ref bean="notifbox-ranger1" />
                <ref bean="trashbox-ranger1" />
                <ref bean="spambox-ranger1" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="socialEntities">
            <list>
            <ref bean="socialEntity3" />
            <ref bean="socialEntity4" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="curricula" ref="curricula1">
        </property>
        <property name="trips">
            <list>
                <ref bean="trip1" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your relation *Message.sender* -> *Actor* is made through intermediate table *message_senders* or something like this:

```
table actors <- table actors_senders(actor_id, sender_id) -> table senders
```

And in table *actors_senders* deleted record with *actor_id=342*.

It is all that I can say before I see the code of your entities.

**EDIT:**

After added code of entities:
You have abstract class *Actor* which is not really abstract nor for Java nor for Hibernate. It is very confusing (including for Hibernate).

Change your class Actor in next way:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Actor extends DomainEntity {
```

May be this will help.

Comment: Nope, relationship message.sender is made by unidirectional relationship with a foreign key on message pointing to actor. There is however a message_actor table for recipients. Also, I'm always repopulating and the same problem happens with newly added messages using the system, so relationships aren't deleted.

Comment: I've added code for the entities, if you need more or repository code, which I don't know if matters, please let me know

Comment: That tag doesn't appear on the notes my college provides me with, but it could certainly be the problem. However, this error appears when I try to populate with the tag you told me about: `code`org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on domain.SocialEntity.actor references an unknown entity: domain.Actor`code` -Any idea? Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, MappedSuperclass is not your case. I have updated code in answer.

Comment: I changed it, and now it populates fine. However, the problem is still the same. Checking on the description of InheritanceType.JOINED, I suppose that data should be stored on Actor table on common properties and on specific role tables on specific role properties, right? I checked the database and the data is still being saved the same way as it was before changing any tag, everything on specific tables and Actor table is empty. Could the population beans need to be changed too? In that case, I don't know how would that be done, because no row "actor_id" has been created on role tables.

Comment: What tables do you have and what content of these tables?

Comment: Actor, which is empty. Ranger, Administrator, Manager etc which have all the properties of superclass and  their own. Each of the extended classes tables have 2 rows with valid data. This data is mapped when populating the database with data in an xml organized in beans. I will update in a minute the main post with examples of the beans.

Comment: Actor table must contains rows for every Ranger, Administrator, Manager etc

Comment: I've added examples of beans for administrator and ranger on the main post. All the actors are mapped like that and are stored on the tables of the extended classes. The superclass table is created but is empty. There are 2 actors of each class.

Comment: See example of joined inheritance strategy: http://www.javaroots.com/2013/07/hibernate-inheritance-joined-strategy.html